# How can I evaluate the constant parameters of a series of linear functions with varying input parameters?

Tags: optimization

I have the following setup of linear functions:

- g<sub>0</sub>(x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>) -> (x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>)
- g<sub>1</sub>(x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>) -> (x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>)
- ... about 30 more cases

Where g<sub>i</sub> is a function parameterized by 6 values (a<sub>i</sub>-f<sub>i</sub>). Which can be described by the following pseudo code:

```
function g:
  Parameters = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
  Variables = (x, y)

  return (
    x * a + y * b + c,
    x * d + y * e + f
  )
```

For each of the 100k runs I have a random, unknown starting condition (x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>), but similar parameters (a<sub>i</sub> - f<sub>i</sub>). As observable I have all the x parameters except the initial condition, eg x<sub>i>0</sub>.

I'm lost as to how to tackle that problem due to the unknown, variable incoming condition of any run. Without it I would simply try to tackle the problem by linear regression. I would appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I’m unclear what the question is. What do you mean by evaluate? Are you trying to solve for the parameters from the inputs and outputs of the equations?